# Issues when freeing an array of regex_t

Tags: c, regex, dynamic-memory-allocation

**The issue:**
I have a set of `C` functions for working with regular expressions (using `regex.h`). They are stored in a structure with an array of `regex_t` type and an `int` number to indicate the number of elements in it. The problems arise when I try to free the structure. There is a commented part in function `free_reg()`. It causes leaks, of course. But without comments, according to AddressSanitizer, happens a SEGV on unknown address. Why does this happen? I really do need my structure here, and I feel like because of the same error a segmentation fault happens in another program of mine.

**Code:**

```
#include <regex.h>
typedef struct REGEX_ARRAY {
    int num;
    regex_t* elem;
}reg_arr;

reg_arr* init_regex(int* flag) {
    reg_arr* new = malloc(sizeof(reg_arr));
    if (new) {
        new->elem = NULL;
        new->num = 0;
    } else {
        *flag = 0;
    }
    return new;
}

reg_arr* add_pat(reg_arr* patterns, regex_t new_pat, int* flag) {
    int num = patterns->num;
    regex_t* temp = realloc(patterns->elem, (num + 1) * sizeof(regex_t));
    if (temp) {
        patterns->elem = temp;
        patterns->elem[num] = new_pat;
        patterns->num = num + 1;
    } else {
        *flag = 0;
    }
    return patterns;
}

int reg_check(regex_t *reg, char *pattern, int I_flag) {
    int res;
    if (I_flag) res = regcomp(reg, pattern, REG_ICASE);
    else res = regcomp(reg, pattern, 0);
    if (res == 0) res = 1;
    else res = 0;
    return res;
}

void free_reg(reg_arr *reg) {
    if (reg) {
        // for (int i = 0; i < reg->num; i++) {   /// fix this!!!!
        //     regfree(&reg->elem[i]);
        // }
        free(reg->elem);
        free(reg);
    } 
}
```

**Asan output:**

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==14841==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x00007e80000a (pc 0x7f6d96ef99c0 bp 0x7ffe022c81c0 sp 0x7ffe022c8160 T0)
==14841==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    #0 0x7f6d96ef99c0 in free_token posix/regcomp.c:3873
    #1 0x7f6d96ef99c0 in free_dfa_content posix/regcomp.c:589
    #2 0x7f6d96f06094 in __GI___regfree posix/regcomp.c:639
    #3 0x5559efeed5bb in free_reg /home/licht/Documents/Knowledge/school21/inProgress/C3_SimpleBashUtils-0/src/grep/grep_regex.c:65
    #4 0x5559efeed838 in main /home/licht/Documents/Knowledge/school21/inProgress/C3_SimpleBashUtils-0/src/grep/grep_regex.c:80
    #5 0x7f6d96e29d8f in __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
    #6 0x7f6d96e29e3f in __libc_start_main_impl ../csu/libc-start.c:392
    #7 0x5559efeec3a4 in _start (/home/licht/Documents/Knowledge/school21/inProgress/C3_SimpleBashUtils-0/src/grep/s21_grep_getopt+0x13a4)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV posix/regcomp.c:3873 in free_token
==14841==ABORTING
```

**EDIT: Minimal, reproducible example:**

```
    int check = 1;
    reg_arr* pats = init_regex(&check);
    regex_t new_reg;
    if (reg_check(&new_reg, "word", 0)) pats = add_pat(pats, new_reg, &check);
    if (reg_check(&new_reg, "int", 0)) pats = add_pat(pats, new_reg, &check);
    free_reg(pats);
    regfree(&new_reg);
    return 0;
}
```

*ASan output with comments:*

```
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 1000 byte(s) leaked in 16 allocation(s).
```

*ASan output without comments:*

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==5590==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x00002f000009 (pc 0x7f24434f99c0 bp 0x7ffe30a2b890 sp 0x7ffe30a2b760 T0)
==5590==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    #0 0x7f24434f99c0 in free_token posix/regcomp.c:3873
    #1 0x7f24434f99c0 in free_dfa_content posix/regcomp.c:589
    #2 0x7f2443506094 in __GI___regfree posix/regcomp.c:639
    #3 0x55cf1ec2e8cd in main /home/licht/Documents/Knowledge/school21/inProgress/C3_SimpleBashUtils-0/src/grep/grep_regex.c:81
    #4 0x7f2443429d8f in __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
    #5 0x7f2443429e3f in __libc_start_main_impl ../csu/libc-start.c:392
    #6 0x55cf1ec2d3a4 in _start (/home/licht/Documents/Knowledge/school21/inProgress/C3_SimpleBashUtils-0/src/grep/s21_grep_getopt+0x13a4)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV posix/regcomp.c:3873 in free_token
==5590==ABORTING
```

Comment: `add_pat()` is suspicious as the lifetime of `new_pat` is in doubt.  Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You have only one or two blocks allocated. The first in **init_regex()** and the second in **add_pat()** if it is ever called. No for loop needed in **free_reg()**.

Comment: The thing is, I only have one structure here. It is created in init_regex(). And within in an array of regex_t is stored. So I feel like I need to free each element of the array. And if not, where is it leaking then?

Comment: The array is within a single block you allocate/reallocate with realloc(). That is, on the first call to add_pat() the element array (for one element) is allocated (by realloc). Following calls either expand the existing array or allocate a new larger array and free the previous one, again done by realloc.